# Generate RESX files from CSHTML

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio, resources

It is possible to automatic create RESX files from CSHTML files in MVC3 or MVC4?
I would like to get resource file for all hardcored text in cshtml

I use Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Please tell me if you found any solution to do that, I need to generate resx files from an existing asp.net core mvc project (cshtml). thank you in advance.

Comment: I didn't find anything, you should write your own tool

Comment: Thank you, I'll do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate resource files and localized views using custom templates in ASP.NET MVC.

#### Overriding ASP.NET MVC Custom Templates

The **Add View** dialog performs code generation that uses T4 templates behind the scenes. These templates can be modified to customize the generated code from these tools. You can also add custom templates.

Basically you have to copy the default templates to your project. This is the path:

`[Visual Studio Install Directory]\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\
[CSharp | VisualBasic]\Web\MVC\CodeTemplates\`

After you copy the templates, you can copy an existing one and change it to generate a .resx file that fits your needs. I wrote an article about it, you can find it here:

[ASP.NET MVC Localization: Generate resource files and localized views using custom templates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/233898/ASP-NET-MVC-Localization-Generate-resource-files-a)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback J. Steen. In this case I'm not pretty sure what I should include, as there are no code samples, it's more a sequence of print screens showing one approach to solve the problem. If someone wants to dig deeper it'll have to download the source code to understand how it really works. Also, it's very unlikely that the link changes, that is an article that is hosted in CodeProject and I'm not going to remove it.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but I feel that the most important is that people can find a solution to their problem(s) ASAP. That's why I posted a link to my article. I've edited my answer, now it includes more information. Thanks again for your feedback :)